# MySQL and Python - "image not found" -- permanent fix?

Tags: python, mysql, django, macos

Everytime I try to run a django app in terminal using a `python manage.py runserver` command I get the following error:

`Referenced from: /Users/myname/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so
  Reason: image not found.
Did you install mysqlclient or MySQL-python?`

To fix it, I just paste

`export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/mysql/lib/`

into my terminal. How can I rearrange my files so that I don't have to paste this in every time? I am working on a Mac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're just using the default terminal, you could put the command in your .bash_profile/.bashrc by running something like

`echo "export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/mysql/lib/" >> ~/.bash_profile`

Switching .bash_profile with your equivalent.Then when you start a new terminal it should already be applied. To apply it immediately just run

`source ~/.bash_profile`

Comment: Works for me on High-Sierra, Python3.6, MySQL 8.0.11 via Oracle website download